# PHP - Checking up on string with regex and push to array

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I have two variables as follows:

```
$string1 = '/test/10/25';
$string2 = '/test/[0-9]+/[0-9]+
```

Is it possible to make PHP compare these two strings and push the actual ID's (10 and 25) into an array like so by using the regex as some sort of guidance?

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 25
)
```

I tried playing around with preg_match() but this just puts everything into the same array key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you

```
<?php

$string1 = '/test/10/25';
$string2 = '/\/test\/([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)/';
$matches = [];
preg_match($string2, $string1, $matches);

$array = [];

for($i = 1; $i < count($matches); $i ++)
{
    array_push($array, $matches[$i]);
}

print_r($array);
```

`$array` will have the matches inside. I had to change the regex string because it was not "valid" for php.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the help! :)